# What is the difference between mathematical and process/control degrees of freedom?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, chemical-engineering, modeling, process-engineering

Taking mathematical DOF as:
$$ DOF= N_{vars}-N_{eqs} $$
How would process, or control degrees of freedom be defined as?
Thanks!

Comment: Why would they be different?

Comment: Welcome. // Such questions shouldn't go without an example.